# What is a better laboratory set up for dehydration of ethanol to form ethene?

Tags: organic-chemistry

as shown in the question, I will have to design a lab on dehydrating ethanol to form ethene. The current method I am using is by heating up ethanol and sulfuric acid with a hot plate under a water bath and collecting ethene by water displacement method. But I wonder how I can improve this method, without changing the chemicals involved.
And I also want to find out how to identify the formation of double bond to test ethene is formed. I used potassium permanganate but because the ethene is a gas, I am not sure if there are other methods of testing it without having the gas escaping.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you intending to collect the ethene?

Comment: Why improve a method working all right ? Is it even possible to improve such a method ? What do you mean by "improve" ? A good test for double bonds is to make your gas bubble through a diluted solution of bromine $\ce{Br2}$, which is brown due to the presence of bromine. In the presence of ethene (or of any double bond)  this solution gets discolored. And if you are not allowed to store bromine water, you may produce it just before use, by mixing bleach ($\ce{NaClO}$ solution) with diluted HCl and NaBr. And then destroying it by an excess $\ce{NaOH}$ after use.

Comment: @Waylander yes, the volume of ethene collected will be my dependent variable.

Comment: @Maurice may I ask for more details? How do you bubble bromine water to the ethene? Because the ethene collected by water displacement method, I am unsure how to add bromine water without having the ethene escaping once I remove the water from the tube which contains the ethene collected. Thank you.

Comment: @xxxx. Apparently your ethene is getting out of some plastic or rubber tubing bubbling through water. So get a fraction of the gas in a test tube under water. Close it with a stopper under water. Save the tube half filled with ethene. Prepare a 1 mL syringe filled with bromine water. Insert a needle between the stopper and the test tube. Inject this brown liquid through the needle into the test tube. Stir. You should see the brown color disappear. If you use more ethene, for example collected in a 100 mL glass balloon instead of a test tube, you should see small droplets of $\ce{C2H4Br2}$.